# Dual gyro system: will it resist a turning force?

Tags: angular-momentum, gyroscopes, precession

Let's say there are 2 gyroscopes. Both are connected to the same frame (orange). Both are spinning at the same speed, but in opposite directions (red).
[image: diagram]
If I spin the frame (green arrow), the gyros will precess. If the orange frame was weak, it would fold in half.
Assuming the orange frame is strong enough, the the gyros' precession would cancel out.
Would the frame-spinning force (green) encounter resistance? Or would it spin just as freely as if the gyros were stopped?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see the result of this experiment on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bzbVwiIeM0M):

1. If the two gyroscopes spin in the same direction, they behave like a single gyroscope with twice the angular momentum. (not part of your question)
2. If the two gyroscopes spin in opposite direction, their angular momentum cancel. They behave like a non-spinning gyroscope. However, be aware that the mount experience "a lot" of stress -- in contrast to the non-rotating gyroscope case.

Comment: Yes, of course the angular momentum will cancel. I want to know if a DRAG FORCE would result in the opposite direction to the green arrow.

Comment: @Botspot: Well, if the angular momentum vanishes, we are allowed to remove the gyroscopes from the system and replace them with static masses -- which is equivalent to non-rotating gyroscopes. I have to admit, considering this system I do not understand the concept of a drag force. If you spin a cylinder about its symmetry axis (in vacuum), what constitutes the drag force?

Comment: OK I referred back to a textbook, and you're right- there is no drag force! I'll have to look more into it, since I *feel* a resistive force when I change the rotation axis of a fidget spinner.

Comment: So you build such a thing, and now you like to understand it. That would have been valuable information. How did you make sure that the axes of rotations are parallel and what is the precision of the mount? After all, the gyro must spin and there will be some clearance.

Answer (score 1):

If the total angular momentum of the two gyros is zero, then no torque is required to change the direction of the angular momentum. Small torques will be required to change the angular velocity of the system about the horizontal axis.